# Execute PHP code in Javascript onclick

Tags: php, ajax, javascript

When a user clicks on the table row, I want to:

- save a value in the user profile
- go to a page

I am within this loop:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'aanvraag', 'posts_per_page' =>'-1', 'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'private'/* , 'trash' */) ) ); ?>
<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This is not working:

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href='http://www.areal-agro.nl/<?php 
    $user = get_the_title();
    update_usermeta( $current_user->id, 'current_user', $user );        
?>'">
```

If I `echo` the `$user` value, it outputs the right (current) value.
If I use the `update_usermeta` as written, it uses the last value.
If I use `update_usermeta( $current_user->id, 'current_user', 'test');` it works.

How can I export the **current** value? Why is `onclick` not behaving like it's in the loop, and how can I improve this?

Comment: Hi Lars, are you familiar with the general concept of AJAX and the [WordPress AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX)?

Comment: I've looked into AJAX but it seems to difficult for me as of yet. Are you saying that the onclick doesn't get the php values realtime?

Comment: The only way to execute some PHP using Javascript is by AJAX. This link on [Ajax in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) will give you some insight on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple terms, window.location.href is javascript, and will run in the browser, but PHP runs on the server. In order to execute `update_usermeta()` you need to open a page with that block of code on it. The best way to do this from a click is to use AJAX (javascript) to visit the URL on which you have this code. Most likely you'll need to create a new PHP file with your code in it and write some AJAX to visit the page.

Comment: Thanks, any hints on how to get started? Or are there any other possibilities of retrieving that value?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to make a static php link with some kind of variable in the url and pass it through to the next page? Such as http:/www.areal-agro.nl/?page-id=740?aanvraag=15?aanvrager=6

Comment: Lars: your static approach will certainly work. Ajax would just mean that the user would not be taken to a separate page - the action would happen in the background. If navigating to a page solves your problem, do that instead. You can always edit it later to run via AJAX with minimal changes. 

Just a small note, the URL you posted is not legal, it should only have one question mark. Additional parameters must use & instead:

http:/www.areal-agro.nl/?page-id=740&aanvraag=15&aanvrager=6